# Why Jenkins not reading my manifest.yml file?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, plugins, cloud-foundry

I am currently using Jenkins to create an automation. I have set my workspace, along with adding "Source Code Management"; my github information and credentials.

**Manifest.yml**

```
applications:
- name:  TestingApp
  memory: 1G
  random-route: false
  path: target/TestingApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  timeout: 180
  buildpack: java_buildpack_offline


  services:
    - Database
    - ELK Logger
```

Under "Build"

I entered 'clean package' as a mvn build step. (this code runs normally).

**Problem lies here**

Post-build Actions

push to Cloud Foundry

CF credentials

-ticked Read configuration from manifest file

```
  Manifest file manifest.yml.
```

My manifest file is in my github repo. But I am receiving an error everytime I build.

```
Cloud Foundry Plugin:
11:02:07 WARNING: No manifest value for hostname. Using app name: Test-Test
11:02:07 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
11:02:07    at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.DeploymentInfo.expandTokenMacros(DeploymentInfo.java:304)
11:02:07    at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.DeploymentInfo.<init>(DeploymentInfo.java:57)
11:02:07    at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.CloudFoundryPushPublisher.perform(CloudFoundryPushPublisher.java:175)
11:02:07    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
11:02:07    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
11:02:07    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
11:02:07    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
11:02:07    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
11:02:07    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
11:02:07    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
11:02:07    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
11:02:07    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
11:02:07 Build step 'Push to Cloud Foundry' marked build as failure
11:02:07 Finished: FAILURE
```

Similar issue found [here](https://github.com/hpcloud/cloudfoundry-jenkins/issues/3)

**Alternative**

A way to fix this is to manually enter configurations in Jenkins UI. But that's not what I really want to do.

Another example [here](http://www.haydonryan.com/using-jenkins-to-build-a-hello-world-spring-boot-app-and-push-to-cloud-foundry/)

**Alternative 2**

Instead of using cloud foundry plugin. When I add a command shell prompt above it works fine. I am assuming that the configuration is not picking up my manifest.yml file

[image: [pic]

Comment: It looks problem in application.

Comment: @KumareshBabu I updated the post.

Comment: Chun Can you update manifest.yml file? So We can figure out the problem.

Comment: Post-build Actions, Where would that read the manifest file from github? or workspace? either way both of the repositories have the same manifest.yml files. @KumareshBabu

Comment: Post-build Actions - It will read the manifest.yml file from github repository. In above post, you mentioned as manifest.yml but it is application.yml. I got example for creating manifest.yml for cloud foundry https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#minimal-manifest

Comment: @KumareshBabu whoops sorry posted the wrong .yml file. I have updated the file.

Comment: I think the format of manifest.yml is incorrect.

Comment: You need to add --- to above of applications:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143807/discussion-between-mike-chun-and-kumaresh-babu).